# How do I make a curtain rail on a curved bay window easy to use?

Tags: curtain-rail

We have a bay window with a curved curtain rail that goes round the bay.   At present it is very hard to pull the curtain along the rail, as the curtain hooks get stack often on the curve.

Solutions please...  (With or without replacing the rail)

Answer (score 2):

If by "stack," you mean that the curtain hooks get out of order, which makes opening the curtains back up impossible, then you could put a small screw or nail in the top/window side of each hook (perhaps two in each hook if it is really bad.)  Or you could just get bigger hooks. That would make it would be impossible for them to overlap.

If the problem is that too much friction is created by pulling on the curtain material, then I would suggest finding a curtain pulley system (or attaching a rod to the middle-most hook on each side of the curtain.)  Such systems would create an entirely horizontal force on the curtain's hooks, as opposed to the diagonal downward force created by simply pulling on the curtain material, which will create friction between the hooks and the rail.  Or, if the rail and hooks are metal, you could simply try oiling them to reduce friction.

If the problem is something other than the hooks overlapping and becoming inseparable, please explain the problem... maybe even a picture would be in order!

Answer (score 2):

Simply spray the track with--ideally--silicone spray, or furniture polish.  Dust builds up over time and the track no long runs smoothly.  If this doesn't work, the track is probably damaged; it can possibly be fixed but it depends what sort of track and if parts are available if it's an old one.  Try the spray first. Then see if any screws on the leading arms need tightening.